Not able to select database for database queries in django
I'm trying to direct my read queries to my read replica in a production setup. Django allows defining multiple databases, so I added two databases like:
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "NAME": "ironbank",
        "ENGINE": "django_postgrespool2",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": os.getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "postgres"),
        "HOST": os.getenv("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
        "PORT": os.getenv("DATABASE_PORT", "5432"),
        "CONN_MAX_AGE": 0,
    },
    "replica": {
        "NAME": "ironbank_replica",
        "ENGINE": "django_postgrespool2",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": os.getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "postgres"),
        "HOST": os.getenv("REPLICA_DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
        "PORT": os.getenv("REPLICA_DATABASE_PORT", "5432"),
        "TEST": {
            "MIRROR": "default",
        },
        "CONN_MAX_AGE": 0,
    },
}


Here I'm using two different databases to test it setup locally.
I also have a database router configured as
file: settings.py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["ironbank.router.PrimaryReplicaRouter"]
---
file: ironbank/router/PrimaryReplicaRouter.py
class PrimaryReplicaRouter:
    @staticmethod
    def db_for_read(model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to a randomly-chosen replica.
        """
        # some model specific logic here, but removed for simplicity
        return "replica"

    @staticmethod
    def db_for_write(model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to primary.
        """
        return "default"

    @staticmethod
    def allow_relation(obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the primary/replica pool.
        """
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def allow_migrate(db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Allow migrations on default database only.
        """
        return db == "default"


Findings

I've been using shell_plus and manual data inspection to check the result being returned by the query is from master or replica. shell_plus directly shows the default database being used for all queries. Doing manual query has also verified data to be coming from master.
Django version is 3.2, which supports the using clause.
Using .using("replica") also did not work. As per docs, it overrides database router definition, and that doesn't work either
Explicitly returning "replica" or "default" works, but .using doesn't


Is it true that the router you used is called when using the model?

yes, added print statements and verified that its called @django.seolpyo.com

add request queries

I'm running queries from django shell (shell_plus).
 Vpa.objects.using("replica").filter(address="a@b").first()
